# Optimization problem with strict inequality constraints and bad behavior on bounds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have an optimization problem

$$f(\vec{a}) = a_1 + \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_{i+1}^2}{a_{i+1}-a_i} \rightarrow \min$$
with constraints $0<a_1< a_2 < \dots < a_n < a_{n+1} = 1$.

I've tried to mitigate my conditions 
$0 \le a_1 \le a_2 \le \dots \le a_n \le 1$, optimize its lagrangian and receive a solution within the region $0<a_1< a_2 < \dots < a_n < 1$, but the singularity of $f(\vec{a})$ near the bounds ruins everything.

What could be an approach to solve this optimization problem?
Any reference or hint is appreciated.

Comment: What is $a_{n+1}$ from the enumerator of the last term of the sum? Is it $a_1$ or something else? If it is $a_1$, then when you subtract the same $\epsilon < a_1$ from each component of the solution, you get a new 'legal' vector $a$ with a smaller value of $f$. So I don't think you can actually reach a minimum. The infimum might still be something nontrivial, though.

Comment: @Ingix, I've edited my post with $a_{n+1} = 1$, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no optimal solution, but $f(\vec{a}) > 1$ and $f(\vec{a})$ can get as close to 1 as desired. See the following for a proof.

For each vector $\vec{a}=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,a_{n+1})$ that satisfies the constrains, all vectors $\vec{a}'= (\epsilon,a_2\ldots,a_n,a_{n+1})$ with $0 < \epsilon < a_1$ also satisfy the constraints, and you have $f(\vec{a}') < f(\vec{a})$ because the lone summand is smaller for $\vec{a}'$ ($\epsilon < a_1$), the $i=1$ summand is smaller because the denominator increased and all other terms stay the same.

In other words, allowing $a_1=0$ seems to be a reasonable extension of the problem, if we are still interested in getting a nontrivial or even sharp lower bound. The function to minimize would then be

$$f(\vec{a}) = \sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{a_{i+1}^2}{a_{i+1}-a_i}}$$

But this is just our original problem with one fewer variable, as the $i=1$ summand is simply $a_2$ because $a_1=0$ holds! This means this still has no optimal solution, as we can make $a_2$ smaller and smaller to decrease the value of $f$. Using the same argument again and again, we find that we can decrease the value of $f$ by setting $a_2=0$, then $a_3=0$, a.s.o. until we have set $a_n=0$. Then we get

$$f((0,0,\ldots,0,1))=\frac{1^2}{1-0}=1,$$

as only the last summand of the sum has a non-zero value. Thus we can conclude that the original problem has no optimal solution, but that $f(\vec{a}) > 1$ under the constraints and that $f$ can get as near to 1 as desired.

Of course, the last paragraph is more of a heuristic than a strict proof, it would of course be nice to have that result in a more easily checkable manner. We always assume that $\vec{a}$ satisfies the original constraints in the following. It is easy to see that

$$\forall\vec{a}:  f(\vec{a}) > 1$$

holds because already the $i=n$ summand of the sum is bigger than 1, it is $\frac{1}{1-a_n}$ with $0 < a_n < 1$, and all other summands are positive.

Let's now take any $0 < \epsilon < 1$ and let's define $\vec{a}$ as follows:

$$a_i=\epsilon^{n+1-i},  i=1,\ldots,n+1$$

This satisfies the constraints, as $a_{n+1}=\epsilon^0=1$ and the $a_i$ are positive and increasing. We get

$$f(\vec{a})=\epsilon+\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{\epsilon^{2(n-i)}}{\epsilon^{n-i}-\epsilon^{n+1-i}}} = \epsilon+\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{\epsilon^{n-i}}{1-\epsilon}}.$$

When we take the limit for $\lim \epsilon \rightarrow 0$, the lone $\epsilon$ goes to zero, obviously. In the sum, the denominator goes to 1 for each summand, while the enumerator goes to $0$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$ and goes to 1 (as a constant) for $i=n$. In other words:

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}{f(\vec{a})} = 1.$$

That means we have found a series of vectors that satisfy the constraints and whose function value approaches 1, as we set out to do.